# Angular2 Styles are not applied without ViewEncapsulation.None

Tags: angular, primeng

I use primeng for datatable component, but the question is about styles in angular. I have the following template:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="values">
    <p-column *ngFor="let column of columns;"
              [header]="column.name"
              [field]="column.field"
              styleClass="{{getColumnCssClasses(column)}}"
             // [styleClass]="getColumnCssClasses(column)" tried this way also
             >
    ...
    </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

So, `p-column` have `styleClass` directive where I can add my own css class.

```
getColumnCssClasses(column) {
   if(column.isToggle) {
      return 'toggle-column';
   }
}
```

CSS:

```
.togggle-column {
    width: 50px;
}
```

In result, I see that my class is applied correctly, but not the styles.
I see styles in the `head` tag:

```
<style>.toggle-column[_ngcontent-nyw-32] {
  width: 55px;
}</style>
```

I understand that problem is Angular add `[_ngcontent-nyw-32]` to my css class, but in the html I have `toggle-coumn` only.  I know that I can fix it using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, but I don't want to. Why binding doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the native directive **ngClass** instead of the **styleClass** from **p-column**.

```
  <p-dataTable [value]="values">
    <p-column *ngFor="let column of columns;"
              [header]="column.name"
              [field]="column.field"
              [ngClass]="{{getColumnCssClasses(column)}}"
             >
    ...
    </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

If that doesn't work you can add this to the container

```
:host  /deep/   .toggle-column { width: 55px; }
```

You can find some more options by reading this blogpost [Angular — Advanced Styling Guide (v4+)](https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/angular-advanced-styling-guide-v4-f0765616e635).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried native `ngClass`, the class is applied, but styles are not and in the html I see: `<td class="toggle-column" ng-reflect-klass="toggle-column"`. Anyway, the class doesn't contain `[_ngcontent-XXXX]`. I will try :host later. Thanks for the answer.